# kdevelop: comment out block

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kdevelop

I can't find any shortcuts for commenting out blocks of code.

before:

```
int main() {
   std::cout << "my awesome program" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

```
// int main() {
//   std::cout << "my awesome program" << std::endl;
//   return 0;
//}
```

This is a pretty essential feature for me and I can't seem to find it anywhere in the menus. Does kdevelop not have this functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course I find it 2 minutes after posting ...

#### comment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

#### uncomment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[list of KDevelop shortcuts](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdevelop/kdevelop/some-useful-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Comment: A shortcut standard for IDE's should be proposed.